# best htaccess multi-rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to find the best rewrite rule for my website...

I have 2 domains example.it and example.com but I have SSL under example.com only.

What I need: each user request should be redirected to **https://www.example.com/...**

Now I'm using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but if I digit http://example.com its redirect me to https://example.com, not www.

Also if I do a GTMetrix test I got an F value under Avoid landing page redirects:

```
Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs.

http://example.it/
http://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/
```

how can I solve? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this in a single redirect rule and avoid multiple redirects. Have your .htaccess containing this rule only:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache when testing this.